# create importable python library

Tags: python, module, pip, package, python-import

I followed this article to create a python package.

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

I created a new project and set up a new virtual environment.
Instead of uploading it to pip and installing it from there i installed it from my local file system with:

```
python -m pip install path/to/.whl
```

retrieving the message:
Installing collected packages: alexs-utils
Successfully installed alexs-utils

I am not able to import my function from my_utils

This is my setup.py:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="alexs_utils",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Example Author",
    author_email="author@example.com",
    description="A small example package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/pypa/my_utils",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    py_modules=['my_utils']
)
```

This is my my_utils.py:

```
def foo():
    print('bar')
```

This is my **init**.py:

```
name = "example_pkg"
```

Comment: Your issue is that you do not add `utils.py` to the distribution; do that by adding `py_modules=['utils']` to the `setup()` arguments. The answer in the linked question has also an example for that.

Comment: on a note they did not do this in this explaination as well : https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

But i tried it out and iam still not able to import

This is not a duplicate.

Comment: _i created a folder with a LICENSE, README.md, setup.py and utils.py_ means that you have the `utils.py` as the standalone module. If you want to put it in a wheel, you have to include it via `py_modules`. I have tested the project setup locally and adding `py_modules` solves the issue, the code `from utils import stuff` works fine after the wheel rebuild and installation.

Comment: _on a note they did not do this in this explaination as well_ because their example includes a package, not a standalone module.